# Sum function in double array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Well I must have to be able to sum the coursePrice of this JSON [JSONLINK](https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/avantica-test/collections/parcial-uno?apiKey=12KfjNX97_amx0iUdS2I_eitAy3jSaOb) on AngularJS (javascript)

And I have to make two sums,one for school and the another all the schools. I already print all the data on a table but im not sure of how to make that javascript function

Comment: Is `coursePrice` really formatted with a dollar sign?

Comment: Yes it is :S im confuse

Comment: If you have control over your backend to change it to a formatless number(wihtout dollar signs and commas) then its easier to sum it up

Comment: I can't change that JSON :S

Comment: hmm so you want to have another array of the sum of each school? or do you want the sum be appended on each school item in the array?

Comment: I want to make two functions: one for sum each school PriceCourse.
And the second will be sum all the PriceCourse of all schools..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem to solve here is to parse the `coursePrice` to a number, to do that you can use `String.prototype.replace()` and then change it to a number.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZFUvOYb6HCWtBr9LcWmm?p=preview)**

something like this:

```
+coursePrice.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
```

wherein the `+` sign changes the replaced string to a number.

Now lets get back to the two functions that you want to create, first lets create a service that will have functions, `getSchoolCoursePrice()` and `getTotalSchoolCoursePrice()`.

*Service*

```
  .service('SchoolService', function() {

    this.getSchoolCoursePrice = function(school) {
      return school.professor.reduce(function(value, professor) {
        return value + +professor.coursePrice.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
      }, 0.00);
    };

    this.getTotalSchoolCoursePrice = function(schools) {
      return schools.reduce(function(value, school) {
        return value + school.totalCoursePrice;
      }, 0.00);
    };

  })
```

`SchoolService.getSchoolCoursePrice()` gets the total course price of a school, as you have noticed that the function accepts a parameter which is a school.

`SchoolService.getTotalSchoolCoursePrice()` on the other hand, accepts a parameter of an array of schools which gets the `totalCoursePrice` of each school. This `totalCoursePrice` is assigned when iterating each school and then using `SchoolService.getSchoolCoursePrice()` to assign it with this property.

*Controller*

```
.controller('SchoolController', function($scope, $http, SchoolService) {

    $http.get('schools.json').success(function(schools) {

      $scope.schools = schools.map(function(school) {
        school.totalCoursePrice = SchoolService.getSchoolCoursePrice(school);
        return school;
      });

      $scope.totalPrice = SchoolService.getTotalSchoolCoursePrice(schools);

    });

  });
```

As you can see the controller, fetches the list of schools and then appends a `totalCoursePrice` property to each school.

*HTML*

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>School</td>
    <td>Total Course Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="!schools">
    <td colspan="2">Loading...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="school in schools track by $index">
    <td ng-bind="school.school"></td>
    <td ng-bind="school.totalCoursePrice"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="schools">
    <td>Total Price</td>
    <td ng-bind="totalPrice"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you started

```
// get numeric value and separate it by ','
var num = coursePrice.split('$')[1].split(","); 
// concatenate numeric string
num = num[0] + num[1]; 
// turn it into a float
num = parseFloat(num);
```

Next time don't expect for someone else to do your work:

```
var sum = 0;

data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.professor.forEach(function(p) {
      var num = p.coursePrice.split('$')[1].split(","); 
      // concatenate numeric string
      num = num[0] + num[1]; 
      // turn it into a float
      num = parseFloat(num);
      allSum += num;
   });
});
```

This will be for all schools, for individual schools you could accomplish this using jQuery $.grep function.

For individual schools without $.grep and jQuery:

```
var schools = [];
var schoolsSum = [];

data.forEach(function(d) {
   if(schools.indexOf(d.school) == -1) {
      schools.push(d.school);
      schoolsSum.push(0);
   }
   var schoolIndex = schools.indexOf(d.school);
   d.professor.forEach(function(p) {
      var num = p.coursePrice.split('$')[1].split(","); 
      // concatenate numeric string
      num = num[0] + num[1]; 
      // turn it into a float
      num = parseFloat(num);
      allSum += num;
      schoolsSum[schoolIndex] += num;
   });
});
```

After this you should have two arrays one containing the schools name, and one the schols course price sums. You can easily create an object whit those two:

```
var schoolsObj = new Object();
var index = 0;
schools.forEach(function(s) {
   schoolsObj[s] =  schoolsSum[index];
   index += 1;
});
```

Comment: i thought on something like this @Teo
unaControllers.contorller("sumCoursePrice",['$scope','UNAService',
                          function($scope,UNAService){
        var sum=0;
                              UNAService.getAllSchools(function(error,data){
                              if(!error){
                                sum+=data.professors.coursePrice;
                              }
                                 return sum;
                              });

}]);
But i don't know if i can do it

Comment: well it is a start but first you need to turn the data.professors.coursePrice value into a float, I could help you getting started with this issue using jQuery, but you didn't specified in the question if you are using it.

Comment: AngularJS is javascript

Comment: I know, but you can use AngularJS side by side with jQuery, this issue could be easily resolved using jQuery ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery but we can try hehe

Comment: I'm sorry i was'nt sure to how to use the for each function on angular. but thanks for the help.

Comment: well, forEach is a javascript function, i think ryeballar answered on this by using angular.